# Same DbContext behaving differently under different projects in a solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-worker-roles, entity-framework-migrations

I have standard asp.net mvc application and using entity framework code first with repository as the back-end. There are no pending migrations and everything works fine when i execute the application.

I added a cloud service project (with one worker role) and used same dbcontext that i was using with my asp.net mvc application but when I run the cloud service on azure emulator, it throws exception saying that the db model was changed and that i need to add migration and update database.

> The model backing the 'xDbContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Case 1: When I add-migration, it gives me some changes that I already executed and they can be seen in the database.

Case 2: When I add-migration from my web application, it creates an empty migration.

Why are the same dbcontext behaving differently under different projects in one solution? I find it really strange or is it me missing something?

I would really appreciate if you can direct me somewhere.
Thanks

Comment: Both cases run against the same database instance?

Comment: Yes. I have a class library which contains my entities, db configurations and dbContext class which is added as reference to both the projects.

Comment: Do both projects that use the library bring in the same version of entity framework? Perhaps it's a silly question, but I can't think it can be anything other than some silly mistake. The changes EF demands in the one case are non-trivial, right? We're talking ALTER TABLE statements, yes?

Comment: Are you 100% sure both are pointing at the same database?, what do your connection strings look like in both projects?

Comment: @AliBaig did you found a reason for this behavior? I have same issue!

Comment: @LucianBumb I don't really remember how i got around it but make sure you have the same connection strings in both the projects.

Comment: @AliBaig thanks, I found that the `EF` version was not the same, after upgrade to 6.1.3 is working.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but remember that which database is used depends on the config files for the running assembly. So running as cloud would use the cloud config, and running the web project would use the web config. And even running unit tests would use the config files in the unit test project.